# Integrate Piwik tracking code into Sphinx-generated docs hosted on readthedocs.io

Tags: python, python-sphinx, matomo, read-the-docs

While readthedocs.io offers the possibility to enable Google Analytics for a page by just adding the tracking ID within a project's settings, the same offer does not seem to exists for using Piwik.

I would like to use Piwik for a page that I generate for a Python project using Sphinx and that is hosted on readthedocs.io. I guess one way to enable it would be to add the Piwik tracking code to the page template as mentioned in https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/199 however I'm not sure how to start with this.

Has someone been able to use Piwki in this configuration or an idea on how to achieve it? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Modify your theme's template, inserting your Piwik tracking code.  [My answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44175925/2214933) can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into that!