# Stop Sphinx from Hyphenating

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a similar question to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5001/prevent-hyphenation-and-use-line-break-in-block-of-text), except for Sphinx and RST. Namely, I would like to prevent text from being hyphenated at the end of the line.

For example I want this:

```
This is my long sent-
ence.
```

To be:

```
This is my long
sentence.
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyphenation is implemented by the stylesheet [`basic.css`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/themes/basic/static/basic.css_t#L219-L224) in the Sphinx theme "basic".

```
div.body p, div.body dd, div.body li, div.body blockquote {
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

You can override these styles with your own.  See my answer to [How do I customize Sphinx RtD Theme default search settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154226/how-do-i-customize-sphinx-rtd-theme-default-search-settings/44175925#44175925)

Your theme may have JavaScript or other styles that implement hyphenation.

For PDF output, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5039

Comment: I copy `basic.css_t` to `_static` folder of my project. This method only works for HTML output but not Latex/PDF outputs.

Comment: I am still looking for solution to stop Sphinx to use hyphenation for Latex/PDF outputs.

Comment: Answer edited after performing a [DuckDuckGo search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=no+hyphenation+latex)

Answer (score 0):

After reading pointers from @steve-piercy, I managed to find a solution for the problem.  I need to customize `conf.py` in my project.  My `conf.py` has the following settings:

```
# ...
# ...

# -- Options for LaTeX output ------------------------------------------------

latex_elements = {
    # The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
    #
    'papersize': 'a4paper',

    # The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
    #
    'pointsize': '12pt',

    # Additional stuff for the LaTeX preamble.
    #
    'preamble': r'''
    \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
    '''

    # Latex figure (float) alignment
    #
    # 'figure_align': 'htbp',

}

# ...
# ...
```

I am using Sphinx 1.8.2, MikTex 2.9 and Strawberry Perl 5.28.1. This new change in `conf.py` will download new perl package(s).

Comment: what do you mean about Perl packages? this looks quite unrelated to using the LaTeX [`hyphenat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat) package in your document.

Comment: AFAIK, those packages are written in Perl. Perl will download missing packages on its own.

Comment: the manager of your TeX installation is quite possibly written in Perl: I don't know about MikTeX, but the `tlmgr` for TeXLive is indeed a Perl script. But `hyphenat` is simply a bunch of LaTeX macros and TeX primitive register settings (such as `\hyphenpenalty=10000\exhyphenpenalty=10000\relax`)  having nothing whatsoever to do with Perl.